# Why would my Html.DropDownList yield a list filled with "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem" strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following model:

```
public class MyModel {
    public int SelectedItemId { get; set; }
    public SelectList PossibleItemsList { get; set; }
};
```

and in my controller I do the following:

```
 var possibleItems = someSource.Select( item => new SelectListItem
                                          {
                                             Text = item.FirstMember,
                                             Value = item.SecondMember
                                          }).AsEnumerable();
 var model = new MyModel();
 model.SelectedItemId = somevalue;
 model.PossibleItemsList = new SelectList(possibleItems, model.SelectedItemId);
 return View( model );
```

and in my view I have this code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedItemId ", Model.PossibleItemsList )
```

and when the code runs the controller code seems to work okay but the view has a dropdown where all items just have "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem" text.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor you are using treats its first argument as a list of objects that should be displayed in a list, and calls `ToString` on each of them to get both text and value for the corresponding list item. If these objects happen to be `SelectListItem` instances  - it makes no difference, they are treated the same. `SelectListItem.ToString` is not defined and calls basic implementation, which is the string representation of the type. That is the why you are seeing list of `"System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem"`.

In your situation you do not need to construct enumerable of `SelectListItem` objects, just use another constructor of `SelectList`:

```
 var model = new MyModel();
 model.SelectedItemId = somevalue;
 model.PossibleItemsList = new SelectList(
     someSource, "FirstMember", "SecondMember", model.SelectedItemId);
 return View(model);
```